# PHP Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT

Tags: php, user-agent

The following code validates the user agent accessing the site however I am getting the error. What do I need to update to accommodate scenarios where there is no user agent being set?

**ERROR**
PHP Notice:  Undefined index:  HTTP_USER_AGENT in Utils.php on line 7

**CODE**

```
public static function detectBrowser()
    {
        $userAgent = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

        if (preg_match('/opera/', $userAgent)) {
            $name = 'opera';
        }
        elseif (preg_match('/webkit/', $userAgent)) {
            $name = 'safari';
        }
        elseif (preg_match('/msie/', $userAgent)) {
            $name = 'msie';
        }
        elseif (preg_match('/mozilla/', $userAgent) && !preg_match('/compatible/', $userAgent)) {
            $name = 'mozilla';
        }
        else {
            $name = 'unrecognized';
        }

        if (preg_match('/.+(?:rv|it|ra|ie)[\/: ]([\d.]+)/', $userAgent, $matches)) {
            $version = $matches[1];
        }
        else {
            $version = 'unknown';
        }

        if (preg_match('/linux/', $userAgent)) {
            $platform = 'linux';
        }
        elseif (preg_match('/macintosh|mac os x/', $userAgent)) {
            $platform = 'mac';
        }
        elseif (preg_match('/windows|win32/', $userAgent)) {
            $platform = 'windows';
        }
        else {
            $platform = 'unrecognized';
        }

        return array(
            'name'      => $name,
            'version'   => $version,
            'platform'  => $platform,
            'userAgent' => $userAgent
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 65, accepted):

The User-Agent header is optional. Firewalls may filter it or people may configure their clients to omit it. Simply check using `isset()` if it exists. Or even better, use `!empty()` as an empty header won't be useful either:

```
public static function detectBrowser() {
    if(empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) {
        return array(
            'name' => 'unrecognized',
            'version' => 'unknown',
            'platform' => 'unrecognized',
            'userAgent' => ''
        );
    }

    // your old code here
}
```

However, since all of your code seems to work fine on an empty string and also yield the "unknown" values you could simply change the following line:

```
$userAgent = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);
```

like this:

```
$userAgent = isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])
               ? strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])
               : '';
```

Answer (score 9):

use isset:

```
if( !isset( $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])){
    $name = "none";
}else{
     $userAgent = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

    if (preg_match('/opera/', $userAgent)) {
        $name = 'opera';
    } [... yourcode ...]
}
```

Comment: Pretty ugly with the huge `else` block IMO

Comment: I know, but that was not the question.