# Can't access cpanel, getting "HTTP ERROR 500"

Tags: php, regex, error-handling, phpmyadmin, server

For some reason I can no longer access my HostPapa cpanel, it's saying:

```
The www.hostpapa.ca page isn’t working
www.hostpapa.ca is currently unable to handle this request.
HTTP ERROR 500
```

I checked my error log and I see this same error repeated for different dates/times:

```
[07-Jun-2016 14:30:26 America/Toronto] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT in /home/saltn168/public_html/tripepic.com/tripepic-theme/List/tripepic-theme.php on line 1160
[07-Jun-2016 19:26:50 America/Toronto] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT in /home/saltn168/public_html/tripepic.com/tripepic-theme/List/tripepic-theme.php on line 1160
[08-Jun-2016 08:45:14 America/Toronto] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT in /home/saltn168/public_html/tripepic.com/tripepic-theme/List/tripepic-theme.php on line 1160
[08-Jun-2016 20:35:00 America/Toronto] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT in /home/saltn168/public_html/tripepic.com/tripepic-theme/List/tripepic-theme.php on line 1160
[08-Jun-2016 23:14:13 America/Toronto] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT in /home/saltn168/public_html/tripepic.com/tripepic-theme/List/tripepic-theme.php on line 1160
```

I checked that file and line 1160 is:

```
if(isset($r[2]) && @$r[2] == 'img' && preg_match('/MSIE [5-7]/',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) == 0) {
```

It looks like gibberish to me so I'm not sure what to make of it. Yesterday my partner made me a "super admin" of the site -- not sure if it could be related to that? or why it would be even.

If anyone can point me in the right direct I'd strongly appreciate it.

Thanks

Comment: Take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130830/php-undefined-index-http-user-agent

Comment: What browser are you using?

Comment: You could add condition `&& isset($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])` before the `preg_match`.

Comment: I'm using Chrome, but I just tried it in Safari and it works. So weird.

Comment: @AngelaMartinez like the question that I posted above said, User-Agent header is optional, so if it is set, there will be no error, if it is not set, there will be an error because you will be trying to acess an index that doesnt exist. So it is best to check if it is set with `isset()`.

Answer (score 1):

The user agent header is an optional header. Something might be filtering it (like a firewall) or people can configure their clients to omit the header.

You might want to check if the header exists with `isset()`.