# Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT

Tags: php

I am trying to perform an action when a specific user agent visits a link.

So i have my code like this:

```
//if browser is not Mozilla/4.2, then do something. 
//but if its Mozilla/4.2, do another thing.

if(strlen(strstr($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"Mozilla/4.2")) <= 0 ){ 
    // Do something
} else {
    //Else do another thing code follows.
}
```

The above code is working but it keeps giving this warning in the error log `"Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT"`

The [solution i saw used pregmatch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130830/php-undefined-index-http-user-agent), but am targeting only a single user agent.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: The error is about `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` specifically. Not if you are using strlen, strstr or preg_match. Check your `$_SERVER` superglobal to see if it contains what it should (`HTTP_USER_AGENT` being among them).

Comment: You may have to resort to a pre-action like: `if (empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'])) { $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] = 'unknown'; }`

Comment: `HTTP_*` headers are user provided headers and the user can choose not to provide them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to check the existence of the index (HTTP_USER_AGENT) on $_SERVER and if it's not set then set it to empty string.

This can be achieved by doing;

```
$userAgent = ! empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) ? $_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] : '';

if(strlen(strstr($userAgent,"Mozilla/4.2")) <= 0 ) { 
    // Do something
} else { 
    // Do something else.
}
```

Comment: If you use PHP 7, you could use something like `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'] ?? 'no user agent'` http://php.net/manual/de/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op

Comment: This doesn't seem to work when user agent is empty, it did something else. Any reason for that?

Comment: Are you talking about my answer or wawa's comment? If it's my answer you're talking about what is it that you want to achieve ! empty($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']) checks to see if the property is set and that it's not an empty string

Comment: I was talking about your answer. Only `"Mozilla/4.2"` is supposed to `Do Something Else`, every other user agent including empty user agent should `Do Something`