# Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT in Laravel for few users

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel framework to check if it mobile using helper.php, but i get sometimes errors in laravel.log with: Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT

My Code
helper.php code:

```
    public static function isMobile() 
{
    return preg_match("/(android|avantgo|blackberry|bolt|boost|cricket|docomo|fone|hiptop|mini|mobi|palm|phone|pie|tablet|up\.browser|up\.link|webos|wos)/i", $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
}
```

view/ code:

```
@if(App\Helper::isMobile())
    <p>it is mobile</p>
@endif
```

Comment: check before if( isset($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]))  or you can use request()->userAgent()

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130830/php-undefined-index-http-user-agent

Comment: @JohnLobo Can you please modify the function and write for me with the if( isset($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]))?

Comment: public static function isMobile() 
{ 
 $userAgent="";
 if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"])){
  $userAgent=preg_match("/(android|avantgo|blackberry|bolt|boost|cricket|docomo|fone|hiptop|mini|mobi|palm|phone|pie|tablet|up\.browser|up\.link|webos|wos)/i", $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]);
 }
  
 
    return $userAgent;
}

Comment: instead of creating your own method ,you can use this library.https://github.com/jenssegers/agent

Answer (score 2):

As a other question answer by @thiefmaster

Ref:[PHP Undefined index: HTTP_USER_AGENT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14130830/php-undefined-index-http-user-agent)

> The User-Agent header is optional. Firewalls may filter it or people
> may configure their clients to omit it. Simply check using isset() if
> it exists. Or even better, use !empty() as an empty header won't be
> useful either:

```
 public static function isMobile() { 
     $userAgent=null; 
      if(isset($_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"])){ 
    $userAgent=preg_match("/(android|avantgo|blackberry|bolt|boost|cricket|docomo|fone|hiptop|mini|mobi|palm|phone|pie|tablet|up\.browser|up\.link|webos|wos)/i", $_SERVER["HTTP_USER_AGENT"]); 
    } 
  return $userAgent; 
}
```

or you can do following

```
 public static function isMobile() { 
         $userAgent=null; 
          if(isset(request()->userAgent())){ 
        $userAgent=preg_match("/(android|avantgo|blackberry|bolt|boost|cricket|docomo|fone|hiptop|mini|mobi|palm|phone|pie|tablet|up\.browser|up\.link|webos|wos)/i",request()->userAgent()); 
        } 
      return $userAgent; 
    }
```

Also i suggest you to use `agent` library
https://github.com/jenssegers/agent